PSQL to TSQL generate string sequence
Need this PSQL equivalent in TSQL
select 'P' || lpad(lvl, length('__'), '0') 
from (select level lvl from dual connect by level <= 14)

I only have access to select statements.
PSQL results are
P01
P02
P04
P05
P06
P07
P08
P09
P10
P11
P12
P13
P14

Research done.
Have used TSQL RIGHT and REPLICATE to make the LPAD equivalent. Need to know the Level and connect by equivalent?

GENERATE_SERIES()

You can use my t-SQL rangeX function to generate the numbers (code below). This will give you the numbers 1 to 10.
SELECT r.RN FROM core.rangeX(1,10,1) AS r;

Returns:
RN
-----
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Note the parameters and solution:
-- Parameters
DECLARE
  @Rows INT     = 14,  -- how many rows you want
  @Char CHAR(1) = 'P', -- character to start the values with
  @Len  INT     = 2;   -- Length of the number after the character

-- Solution
SELECT   
  SomeID = CONCAT(@Char,REPLICATE(0,@Len-LEN(r.RN)), r.RN)
FROM  core.rangeX(1,@Rows,1) AS r;

Returns:
SomeID
--------
P01
P02
P03
P04
P05
P06
P07
P08
P09
P10
P11
P12
P13
P14

If you had more than 100 and wanted to start with "X" you would use these parameters:
DECLARE
  @Rows INT     = 200,  -- how many rows you want
  @Char CHAR(1) = 'X', -- character to start the values with
  @Len  INT     = 3;   -- Length of the number after the character

Returns:
SomeID
----------
X001
X002
X003
X004
X005
... rows removed for readability
X198
X199
X200

RangeX code:
CREATE   FUNCTION core.rangeX
(
  @Low  BIGINT,
  @High BIGINT,
  @Gap  BIGINT
)
/****************************************************************************************
[Purpose]:
 Creates a lazy, in-memory, forward-ordered sequence of up to 1,073,741,824 integers
 beginning with @Low and ending with @High (inclusive). RangeX is a pure, 100% set-based
 alternative to solving SQL problems using iterative methods such as loops, cursors and
 recursive CTEs. RangeX is based on Itzik Ben-Gan's getnums function for producing a
 sequence of integers and uses logic from Jeff Moden's fnTally function which includes a
 parameter for determining if the "row-number" (RN) should begin with 0 or 1.
 
 I used the name "RangeX" because it functions and performs almost identically to
 the Range function built into Python and Clojure. RANGE is a reserved SQL keyword so I 
 went with "RangeX". Functions/Algorithms developed using RangeX can be easilty ported
 over to Python, Clojure or any other programming language that leverages a lazy sequence.
 The two major differences between RangeX and the Python/Clojure versions are:
   1. RangeX is *Inclusive* where the other two are *Exclusive". range(0,3) in Python and
      Clojure return [0 1 2], core.RangeX(0,3) returns [0 1 2 3].
   2. RangeX has a fourth Parameter (@Row1) to determine if RN should begin with 0 or 1.

[Author]:
 Alan Burstein

[Compatibility]: 
 SQL Server 2008+

[Syntax]:
 SELECT r.RN, r.OP, r.DM, r.N, r.NOP
 FROM   core.RangeX(@Low,@High,@Gap) AS r;

[Parameters]:
 @Low  = BIGINT; The lowest  value for N.
 @High = BIGINT; The highest value for N.
 @Gap  = BIGINT; The distance between each N value.
 
[Returns]:
 Inline Table Valued Function returns:
 RN  = BIGINT; a row number that works just like T-SQL ROW_NUMBER() except that it can 
       start at 0 or 1 which is dictated by @Row1. If you need the numbers: 
       (0 or 1) through @High, then use RN as your "N" value, ((@Row1=0 for 0, @Row1=1),
       otherwise use N1.
 OP  = BIGINT; returns the "finite opposite" of RN. When RN begins with 0 the first number 
       in the set will be 0 for RN, the last number in will be 0 for OP. When returning the
       numbers 1 to 10, 1 to 10 is retrurned in ascending order for RN and in descending 
       order for OP.
       Given the Numbers 1 to 3, 3 is the opposite of 1, 2 the opposite of 2, and 1 is the
       opposite of 3. Given the numbers -1 to 2, the opposite of -1 is 2, the opposite of 0
       is 1, and the opposite of 1 is 0.
       The best practie is to only use OP when @Gap > 1; use core.O instead. Doing so will
       improve performance by 1-2% (not huge but every little bit counts)      
 DM  = BIGINT Distance From the median rownumber
 N   = BIGINT; This is the "N" in your tally table/numbers function. this is your *Lazy* 
       sequence of numbers starting at @Low and incrimenting by @Gap until the next number
       in the sequence is greater than @High.
 NOP = BIGINT; Finite opposite of N

[Dependencies]:
 None

[Developer Notes]:
 1.  core.RangeX returns one billion rows in exactly 90 seconds on my laptop:
     4X 2.7GHz CPU's, 32 GB - multiple versions of SQL Server (2005-2019)       
 2.  The lowest and highest possible numbers returned are whatever is allowable by a 
     bigint. The function, however, returns no more than 531,441,000,000 rows (8100^3). 
 3.  @Gap does not affect RN, RN will begin at @Row1 and increase by 1 until the last row
     unless its used in a subquery where a filter is applied to RN.
 4.  @Gap must be greater than 0 or the function will not return any rows.
 5.  If you only need is a sequential set beginning at 1 then, for best performance, use
     the RN column. Use N for when @Low != 1, and/or when @Gap > 1. 
 6.  @Gap must be a positive integer or the function will not return any rows.
 7.  The function will not return any rows when one of the following conditions are true:
       * any of the input parameters are NULL
       * @High is less than @Low 
       * @Gap is not greater than 0
 8.  There is no performance penalty for sorting by RN ASC; there is a large performance 
     penalty, however for sorting in descending order. If you need a descending sort the
     use OP in place of RN then sort by rn ASC. 

[Usage Examples]:
--===== 0. Basic example
SELECT r.* FROM core.rangeX(-9,23,5) AS r;

--===== 1. Using RN (rownumber)

*** The Examples below are the best practices for using this function ***

--===== 1. Using RN (rownumber)
 --== (1.1) The best way to get the numbers 1,2,3...@High (e.g. 1 to 5):
 SELECT   r.RN
 FROM     core.RangeX(1,5,1) AS r
 ORDER BY r.RN;

--===== 2. Using OP for descending sorts without a performance penalty
 --== (2.1) Best Practice for getting the numbers 5,4,3,2,1 (5 to 1):
 -- 2.1.1. DONT do this:
 SELECT   r.RN
 FROM     core.RangeX(1,5,1) AS r 
 ORDER BY R.RN DESC;

 -- 2.1.1. DO this instead:
 SELECT   r.OP
 FROM     core.RangeX(1,5,1) AS r 
 ORDER BY R.RN;

 --== (2.2) Best Practice for getting the numbers 5,4,3,2,1,0 (5 to 0):
 -- 2.2.1. DONT do this:
 SELECT   r.N
 FROM     core.RangeX(0,5,1) AS r
 ORDER BY r.RN DESC;

 -- 2.2.2. DO this instead:
 SELECT   r.NOP 
 FROM     core.RangeX(0,5,1) AS r
 ORDER BY r.RN ASC;

--===== 3. Using N
 -- (3.1) To begin with numbers other than 0 or 1 use N1 (e.g. -3 to 3):
 SELECT   r.N
 FROM     core.RangeX(-3,3,1) AS r
 ORDER BY r.RN;

 -- (3.2) ROW_NUMBER() is built in. If you want a ROW_NUMBER() include RN:
 SELECT   r.RN, r.N
 FROM     core.RangeX(-3,3,1) AS r
 ORDER BY r.RN;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Revision History]:
 Rev 00.0 - 20140518 - Initial Development - AJB
 Rev 01.0 - 20151029 - Added 65 rows. Now L1=465; 465^3=100.5M. Updated comments - AJB
 Rev 02.0 - 20180613 - Complete re-design including opposite number column (op)
 Rev 03.0 - 20180920 - Added additional CROSS JOIN to L2 for 530B rows max - AJB
 Rev 04.0 - 20200329 - 1. Removed startup predicate that dicatated that:
                          @High >= @Low AND @Gap > 0 AND @Row1 = @Row1.
                          That means that this must be handled outside the function 
                       2. Removed the ISNULL Logic from the TOP statement. This will make
                          errors possible if you provide bad parameters. 
                       3. Now using core.rowz() to build the rows - AJB
 Rev 05.0 - 20201001 - Redesigned leveraging fnTally by Jeff Moden
 Rev 06.0 - 20240625 - Final redesign - AJB
*****************************************************************************************/
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
WITH T(N) AS ( -- 90*90*90=729000, 729000*729000 = 531,441,000,000 Rows Total
 SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES
  (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
  (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
  (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
  (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
  (0),(0)) T(N)), -- 90 values
L(N)   AS (SELECT 1 FROM T CROSS JOIN T AS T2 CROSS JOIN T AS T3),
iTally AS (SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM L CROSS JOIN L AS L2)
SELECT TOP((@high-@low+1)/@gap+SIGN((@high-@low+1)%@gap))
  RN  = i.RN,
  OP  = o.OP,
  DM  = (i.RN-o.OP)/2,
  N   = @low+(i.RN-1)*@gap,
  NOP = @low+(o.OP-1)*@gap
FROM        iTally                                                  AS i
CROSS APPLY (VALUES((@high-@low+1)/@gap+SIGN((@high-@low+1)%@gap))) AS r(T)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(r.T-i.RN+1))                                    AS o(OP)
ORDER BY    RN;


This would be the answer I'm looking for if I had access to the create function. I only have access to Select statements for this job.
